# How to open a React Bootstrap modal from a Rails view file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs

I'll do my best to explain my points of confusion.

In our `index.html.erb` file we have the text "Login" which is intended to link to trigger the opening of a simple modal form. Right now, all I want is to do is *merely open the modal.* I have the following code for the link which I suspect is potentially wrong to begin with.

`<%= link_to 'Login', login_path,  {:remote => true, 'data-toggle' =>  "modal", 'data-target' => '#modal-window'} %>`

Am I dealing with a remote modal? I don't know. Anyway, as I can see the `/login` endpoint when I hover over the link I do believe this successfully interacts with the route I defined in our `routes.rb` file, but to what extent, I haven't a clue.

`get '/login', to: 'sessions#new', as: 'login'`

Bear in mind, I've only gotten this far because we have another app that has a login page (not a modal) that I've been referring to. And so the next thing I figured out was to create the following files:

```
app/views/sessions/new.html.erb
app/javascript/packs/sessions/new.js
app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb
```

In the `sessions_controller.rb` file, I just have the new action defined and nothing else:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end
end
```

From this point forward is when I really start to get overwhelmed and confused. My feeling is that the `new.html.erb` file is what should be calling the React code, somehow? Because this is how I saw it was done for the other app's login functionality, here is what I have even though I know it's wrong - but why? What am I missing?

```
<% content_for :page_title do %>Login<% end %>
<% content_for :container_class do %>sessions-container<% end %>
```

In `new.js` I have the following code for the Bootstrap (which is being included elsewhere in our app) modal (I'm not even importing the `react-bootstrap` module or following the ReactModal syntax because this was leading to a whole new set of questions and confusion):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import axios from 'axios'

export default class SessionsNew extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="modal" tabIndex="-1" role="dialog">
          <div className="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div className="modal-content">
              <div className="modal-header">
                <h5 className="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" className="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
              </div>
              <div className="modal-body">
                <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
              </div>
              <div className="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                <button type="button" className="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Finally, I added the `SessionsNew` component to another JS file we have at the same level as our `application.js` file, though I'm not fully understanding why:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import ProductsShow from './products/show'
import SessionsNew from './sessions/new'

const components = {
  'products/show':    { component: <ProductsShow /> },
  'sessions/new':     { component: <SessionsNew /> }
}

if (gon.page_data_controller && gon.page_data_action) {
  const componentKey = gon.page_data_controller + "/" + gon.page_data_action
  if (components[componentKey]) {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
      ReactDOM.render(components[componentKey].component, document.getElementById('content-container'));
    })
  }
}
```

I'm very sorry as I know this hasn't been a straightforward question but more of a cry for help, for any clarity on any piece of what I've just shared. In a nutshell, here are some things I'm wondering:

What exactly am I routing to? What is the flow of events, i.e. the link routes to the login path, and then? What is the purpose of the `new.html.erb` file in contrast to the `new.js` file? Am I correct in understanding that I should create components for each aspect of the modal - from handling the state (open, close, etc.) to handling the login form interaction?

Thank you for reading, any help is appreciated, apologies for the essay.

Answer (score 2):

One solution to your problem:

1) Create a partial for your login form (your modal). Let's say named `_login.html.erb`
2) Add the partial somewhere in your index.html.erb file
3) The modal should have a display none by default.
4) Add an onclick event listener to your login link that changes the display of the modal. For example 
`link_to 'Login', '#', :onclick => 'displayLoginModal'`
You'll need to add some javascript to handle the click event. This link might be helpful: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp